# How to use Cascading Type Params in this situation?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Index.razor.cs:

I am developing a grid compoenent which will display a list of items to it:

```
<Grid Items="Transactions">
    <GridHeader>
        <GridColumn TItem="Transaction">ID</GridColumn>
        <GridColumn TItem="Transaction">Date</GridColumn>
    </GridHeader>
</Grid>
```

Then in Grid.razor.cs and GridColumn.razor.cs I use typeparam TItem.  But It seems I need to pas TITem as a parameter in every grid column, how can I implement support for something like the below instead:

```
<Grid Items="Transactions" TItem="Transaction">
    <GridHeader>
        <GridColumn>ID</GridColumn>
        <GridColumn>Date</GridColumn>
    </GridHeader>
</Grid>
```

Therefore TItem would would cascade down to all child compoenents (regalrdless of ghow deeply nested they are)

I have a had a look at CascadingTypeParam but information on it is scarce so I'm not sure how to go about using it if it is the solution for the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the top of Grid.razor add:

```cs
@attribute [CascadingTypeParameter(nameof(TItem))]
```

#### CascadingTypeParameter

> Denotes the generic type parameter as cascading. This allows generic type inference to use this type parameter value automatically on descendants that also have a type parameter with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this initially but it didn't work and that is because in my example I didn't realise I had to add the type parameter to GridHeader as well before it could cascade down to GridColumn.  I was simply adding my typeparam to GridColumn assuming it would infer the type itself by traversing up the relationship chain