# How do you pass a parent components parameter through a generic wrapper component and further into a child component when using @typeparam?

Tags: c#, blazor, telerik

How to pass objects through generically typed wrapper components, through to the child in blazor.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74494578/how-to-use-cascading-type-params-in-this-situation

Answer (score 0):

I tried to pass props down through these ways

1st Way

```
public delegate void MyRenderFragment(string parameter1, int parameter2);

public partial class MyParentComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public MyRenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public string MyParameter1 { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public int MyParameter2 { get; set; }
    
    // ...
}
```

```
public partial class MyParentComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<string> ChildContent { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public string MyParameter { get; set; }
    
    // ...
}
```

```
@ChildContent((parameter1, parameter2) => (
    <div>
        <p>My parameters are: {parameter1} and {parameter2}</p>
    </div>
))
```

2nd Way

```
<!-- Define the child content element in the parent component -->
<ParentComponent>
  <ChildContent>
    @context => {
      @* Use the parameters passed into the child content element *@
      <div>@context.Param1</div>
      <div>@context.Param2</div>
      <div>@context.Param3</div>
    }
  </ChildContent>
</ParentComponent>

<!-- Use the parent component and pass values for the Param1, Param2, and Param3 properties -->
<ParentComponent Param1="value1" Param2="value2" Param3="value3" />
```

3rd Way

```
<!-- Define the child content element in the parent component -->
<ParentComponent>
  <ChildContent>
    @(item) => {
      <ChildComponent Item="@item" Param1="@Param1" Param2="@Param2" />
    }
  </ChildContent>
</ParentComponent>

<!-- Use the parent component and pass values for the Param1 and Param2 properties -->
<ParentComponent Param1="value1" Param2="value2" />
```

But the only way that it actually passed the data down into the razor child component, was wrapping the component within a CascadingParameter and then OnParameterSet it was set when it was updated in the parent component.

```
     <CascadingValue Value="@theme">
            <article class="content px-4">
                @theme
            </article>
      </CascadingValue>

@code {
    private string theme;
}
```

I spent hours on this so its more for me than for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't exactly clear about whar you're trying to do and you mention `@typeparam` but never show any code using it.

While casacading has it's place, I don't think you need to use it in this case.

A generic RenderFragment is defined as:

```cs
public delegate RenderFragment RenderFragment<TValue>(TValue value);
```

i.e. it only takes one argument of type `TValue`.

So, if we want to pass in multiple values, we need to either:

1. Use a `Tuple`.
2. Define and use a simple data struct such as a `record`.

```cs
public record MyData(string stringValue, int intValue);
```

We declare the delegates like this:

```cs
public delegate RenderFragment MyRenderFragment(MyData value);

public delegate RenderFragment MyRenderFragmentTuple(Tuple<string, int> value);
```

And then our component - mine is called `MyForm`

```cs
<div class="m-2 p-2 bg-light">

   @Display(new MyData("Fred", 1))

   @DisplayTuple(new Tuple<string, int>("Blazor", 50))

</div>

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public MyRenderFragment Display { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public MyRenderFragmentTuple DisplayTuple { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Display);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(DisplayTuple);
    }
}
```

And `Index`:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<MyForm Display=this.renderFragment DisplayTuple=this.renderFragmentTuple/>

@code {
    private RenderFragment renderFragment(MyData value) => (__builder) =>
    {
        <div class="alert alert-info">
        @value.stringValue : @value.intValue.ToString()
        </div>
    };

    private RenderFragment renderFragmentTuple(Tuple<string, int> value) => (__builder) =>
    {
        <div class="alert alert-primary">
            @value.Item1 : @value.Item2.ToString()
        </div>
    };
}
```

[image]